# How echo a date field in php

Tags: nodes, panels

I am trying to call a custom date field to use in a text pane from a node to use as YYYY-mm-dd in:

```
<div class="swod-date swod-hide">yyyy-mm-dd</div>
```

I have tried to use:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($node->field_custom_date['und'][0]['value']));?>
```

but this is not working.  I have tied to just print the php but get a result of 1970-01-01 instead of the date in the field.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure **$node->field_custom_date['und'][0]['value']** returns timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Check [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7.x) function. We can also pass timezone from date field (if any). For example on how to use this function check [Formatting the way the date/time is displayed](https://www.drupal.org/node/71106).

```
$custom_date = strtotime($node->field_custom_date['und'][0]['value']);
echo format_date($custom_date, 'custom', 'D j M Y');
```

Comment: I tried this but it is still nothing is displaying.  I am putting the code in a text pane in panelizer using the php filter.  When I just put echo date("Y-m-d"); I can get the current date to display.

Comment: Did you tried checking the actual output of `$node->field_custom_date['und'][0]['value']` field in node object, whether it is a Timestamp or Human Readable date format. That will help us print date properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($node->field_custom_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']))
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain **what** this code is doing, that will reduce the risk that this will be perceived as a "low quality answer", and deleted via moderation. Just a suggestion ...